# Cucumber, Rails: has_content? test passes even though the string isn't there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Scenario is:

```
    Scenario: View welcome page
    Given I am on the home page
    Then I should see 'Welcome'
```

And definition of the step is

```
Then("I should see {string}") do |string|
  page.has_content?(string)
end
```

The test passes whether the word "welcome" is in the home page or not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step will only fail if it throws an exception. By its naming convention, the `has_content?` method returns false if the content is not in the page, and thus does not throw an exception. This will cause your step to "pass" when you intend it to fail.

You need to make an assertion with some sort of unit testing library (my Ruby is a little rusty)

```rb
Then("I should see {string}") do |string|
  page.has_content?(string).should_be true
end
```

You'll need something like RSpec to gain access to a library allowing you to make assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this the way shown in the other answer will work but will not give useful error messages. Instead you want

For RSpec

```
expect(page).to have_content(string)
```

For minitest

```
assert_content(string)
```

For others

```
page.assert_content(string)
```

Note that assert_content/assert_text and have_content/have_text are aliases of each other so use whichever reads better.